# Scheme - Recursion of an argument at the end of a begin statement?

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I would like some clarifications or resources about the mechanics of "begin" + function + call to a variable, as is the case with the cond structure and the calls to "node" in the following function.

To be frank, I don't understand why failing to call the loop back to "node" would lead to an error in which node isn't anymore a node object as described below.

In fact, while I intuitively undestand that if I call "tree" changing the value of "node" I then should reinstate the original value, I don't undestand why this would need to be done undest the second check, since the value if "node" is not changed there..

I guess that my doubt is about the construct of "begin", since if in the case of a loop function I understand that the loop has to be called at the end of a "begin" statement I don't understand what should an argument be called for..

```
(define tree
  (lambda (node value)
    (cond
      ((null? node)
       (make-node value)) ; if I insert node at the end of this line I just get () as an output
      ((= value (node-value node))
       (node-counter-set! node (+ 1 (node-counter node)))
       node) ; in this position in Dr. Racket a simple ")" would do, but the Petit Chez Scheme implementation that we use for tests in class requires the call to "node"
      ((< value (node-value node))
       (node-left-set! node (tree (node-left node) value))
       node)
      (else
       (node-right-set! node (tree (node-right node) value))
       node)
      )))
```

this is part of a larger system that includes:

```
(define build
  (lambda (root lon)
    (cond
      ((null? lon)
       lon)
      (else
       (build (tree root (car lon)) (cdr lon))
       ))))

(define make-node
  (lambda (value)
    (vector '() value '() 1)
    ))

(define node-counter-set!
  (lambda (node value)
    (vector-set! node 3 value)
    ))

(define node-left-set!
  (lambda (node value)
    (vector-set! node 0 value)
    ))

(define node-right-set!
  (lambda (node value)
    (vector-set! node 2 value)
    ))

(define node-value
  (lambda (node)
    (vector-ref node 1)
    ))

(define node-counter
  (lambda (node)
    (vector-ref node 3)
    ))

(define node-left
  (lambda (node)
    (vector-ref node 0)
    ))

(define node-right
  (lambda (node)
    (vector-ref node 2)
    ))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is as you forgot to include a test case that exhibits it, but `build` should return `root` as its base case, since that's the tree you've been building.

Comment: I guess you-re right about `root`, it makes sense on a design perspective.

Comment: As for my question: why should I call `node` after the conditional expressions in `tree`(in fact, as a part of the conditional expressions)? also: why do some interpreters require it even if its value has not been changed in the expression?

Comment: On a more general level: how should I close a `begin` statement?

Comment: (as for the test case, any will do. as soon as you cancel the call to `node`. one example may be: `(build '() '(3 6 9 4 2 3 7 8 9 3))`, the program will output an error in which `vector-ref` is called on a void expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often with mutating procedures like `vector-set!` the expression evaluates to some undefined value. By undefined we mean the implementer has the choice to put whatever they want. Most implementations then choose an object to be the "undefined" object, but some might choose to return the object that was mutated spearing you from having to do it explicitly in that very implementation. Be careful since if you use implementation specific features you get implementation specific code and not something conforming to the Scheme reports!

If you want `node-counter-set!` to evaluate to the argument you do that in your procedure:

```
(define (node-counter-set! node value)
    (vector-set! node 3 value) ; set value on the node. It returns an undefined value
    node)                      ; last expression in the explicit begin we return the node
```

**BEGIN**

`begin` is a special form that evaluates the expressions in order and for every expression except the last one we just throw away the result. Thus in order for those expressions to be useful they need to have side effects like mutation or input/output.

There are `begin` many places without it being put directly. E.g. the body of a procedure has implicit `begin`:

```
(lambda (x y)
  (display x)
  (newline)
  (display y)
  (newline)
  (+ x y)) ; procedure returns the sum of it's arguments but have lots of sife effects first
```

A `cond` may have more than one consequent in each term, which is an explicit `begin`

```
(cond
  ((= x y) (display "X and Y are same number") (+ x y))
  ...)
```

Actually it's syntactic sugar for:

```
(if (= x y) 
    (begin (display "X and Y are same number") (+ x y))
    ...)
```

Comment: that's very clear. in the example above `make-node` returns the value of the vector (as `vector .. ` will just do that), but all the `..-set!` expressions won't, as `vector-set!` itself doesn't give any output. I guess it's on the programmer to create tools that have a consistent behaviour, but for the exercise above I had to use that set of procedures as it is and adding `((null? node) (define node (make-node value))` inside of `tree`, seems a bit overkill. if I could change them I could just insert the value in the lower level function and spare me the headache of adding it later.

Answer (score 3):

> "how should I close a begin statement?"

with any expression you want. When evaluated, the value of that expression is returned as the value of the whole `begin` expression.

Scheme is expression-oriented language. Each code snippet in it - each *form* - is an expression, not statement — it has some value.

Variables are not "called", they are "referred to", their *values* are used.

Sometimes the value that is referred to by a variable is "mutated" - changed. E.g.

```
(vector-set! var ... )
```

changes the actual contents of the vector referred to by `var`. If you were to write `(set! var 2)` you would change the variable's *binding*, i.e. you would change what object it refers to (heretofore, the number *2*).

Functions that use such mutating operations are said to have *"(side) effects"* in addition to returning some value as all functions do. Here the effect will be the alteration of actual memory resident object, a vector, presumably accessible in other parts of the program.

Answer (score 2):

The value of a `begin` block is the value of the last expression in the block

```
> (define x (begin (print "hello") 3 2 1))
"hello"
> x
1
```

Implementations may differ regarding the value of vector-mutating expressions - some return the modified vector, while some return `void` or something equivalent.
Thus, in your `tree` procedure, some implementations will require you to explicitly give `node` as the value of the expression (and it's a good habit to be explicit and not rely on side effects, anyway).

Comment: this answer made me understand the mechanics of `begin`, that's cool considering that my teacher tried this at least twice without success. thank you.